# Convert DISTINCT in Agregate COUNT to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, distinct

I am converting following SQL into LINQ using Linqer

```
SELECT CC.col1,CC.col2,CC.col3 FROM dbo.Table1 CC
WHERE CC.Status IN (0,3) AND CC.col4 IN (2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY CC.col1,CC.col2,CC.col3
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CC.Status) = 2
```

but it shows following error

SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: DISTINCT in Agregate COUNT cannot be converted to LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the sql select as follows:

```
SELECT CC.col1,CC.col2,CC.col3 FROM dbo.Table1 CC
WHERE CC.Status IN (0,3) AND CC.col4 IN (2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY CC.col1,CC.col2,CC.col3
HAVING (select  COUNT(DISTINCT CC.Status) FROM dbo.Table1 CC) = 2
```

and output in **Linqer** will look like as follows:

```
 from CC in db.Table1
  where
 (new int[] {0, 3 }).Contains(CC.Status) &&
 (new int[] {2, 3, 4, 5 }).Contains(CC.col4)
 group CC by new {
   CC.col1,
   CC.col2,
   CC.col3
 } into g
 where
 ((from Table1 in db.Table1
 select new {
  g.Key.Status
}).Distinct()).Count(p => g.Key.Status != null) == 2
 select new {
   g.Key.col1,
   g.Key.col2,
   g.Key.col3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is failing on this section in the final clause `COUNT(DISTINCT CC.Status)`. If you remove the `DISTINCT` it may be able to convert the SQL. In the section where you see it doing the `Status.Count()` change it to `Status.Distinct().Count()` and you should be good.